# Why do I keep getting this error message in Python?

Tags: python

Trying to write a simple code for class. List of names with values from a .txt file, display these names, sum the values, find the lowest and highest, calculate the average and display the results. However, I can't get pass this error message. I know there is no such thing as a dumb question but feeling pretty dumb right now. Thanks in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Lab5read_file.py", line 34, in <module>
    fname, lname, number = line.split(",")         # Split the input into the 
                                                       contained fields.
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give us that actual input line, but it appears that `line` contains no commas.  Thus, it returns a list of one item.  The left-hand side of your assignment requires *exactly* three items.

Comment: Realize that I had an extra line in my text file. Fixed and it works now. Cheers.